# Are there known benchmark examples where Cover universal portfolio performs better than naive uniform CRP and Split-and-Forget?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory

I am investigating the performance of Cover universal portfolios cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_portfolio_algorithm (and references therein).

I would like to know if there are any benchmarks to test such algorithms. In particular are any 'classical' examples where the Cover U.P. is better than the simple naive CRP (Constant Relative Proportions with 1/n of wealth in each asset, rebalanced thereafter keeping the proportions) and also better than the "Split-and-Forget" allocation (that only trades at t=0 buying 1/n of initial wealth worth of each asset, with no rebalancing) ?

Maybe I'm wrong but in many cases I tested the "naive" CRP(1/n,...,1/n) has better results than Cover's U.P., for instance the examples in Cover's initial paper.

For the example of 2 assets (one constant and another with price relatives 2,0.5,2,0.5 from the Helmbold et al, 1998 [link](http://rob.schapire.net/papers/HelmboldScSiWa98.pdf), Ordentlich and Cover, 1996 [link](https://isl.stanford.edu/%7Ecover/papers/cover_ordentlich_96.pdf)) Split-and-Forget is worse than Cover which is worse than CRP(1/2,1/2).

I'm sure one can came up with artificial examples where Cover U.P. is better than CRP(1/n,1/,...,1/n) and Split-and-Forget but I wonder if some of them are known and "classical" (and possibly from market data)...

best,
G.